# How do i get the socket to continue listening to the client and continuosly print information from the client

Tags: python, server

**Server Side** (server prints the first line of information sent from the client then it JUST STAYS open and doesn't seem to continue listening it just stays open. Is there a way to get the server to listen to the client more and print?)

```
import time

import socket

import signal

from datetime import datetime
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(1024) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connectionn

def clientsocketentry():
    while True:
      connection, addr = serversocket.accept()
      buf = connection.recv(64)

      if not buf:
          break

      elif buf == 'killsrv':
          connection.close()
          sys.exit()

      else:
          print (buf)
          buf = buf.decode("utf-8")
          buf = buf.split(',')
          serverLong = buf[0]
          print('Longitude:' + '' + serverLong)
          serverLat = buf[1]
          print('Lattitude:' + '' + serverLat)
          serverAlt = buf[2]
          print('Altitude:' + '' + serverAlt)
          serverTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
          print('Time of Entry:' + ' ' + serverTime)
          connection.close()



clientsocketentry()
```

**Client Side** (I am only able to send one of the strings of information then the server stays open ut does not take more information from the client)

```
import socket

import time

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))

a = '39.163100,-76.899428,0'
clientsocket.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(5)

a = '4.2,2.2415,0'
clientsocket.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(5)

a = '43454,354354,35435'
clientsocket.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(5)

a = '435742.,35.452,52434'
clientsocket.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(5)


clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Please don't shout so loud... IMHO, it really hurts readability

Comment: sorry about that. = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accept one single connection at a time (no need for a 1024 backlog then...) you can simply nest 2 loops: the outer one waiting for new connections the inner one processing input from the only one established connection. If you need to process more than one connection, you will have to use `select` or threads.

Here is an example for one single connection:

```
def clientsocketentry():
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
    serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connectionn
    cont = True
    while cont:
      connection, addr = serversocket.accept()
      while True:
          buf = connection.recv(64)

          if len(buf) == 0:     # end of connection
              connection.close()
              break

          elif buf == b'killsrv':     # request for closing server (beware of the byte string)
              connection.close()
              serversocket.close()
              cont = False
              break

          else:
              print (buf)
              buf = buf.decode("utf-8")
              buf = buf.split(',')
              serverLong = buf[0]
              print('Longitude:' + '' + serverLong)
              serverLat = buf[1]
              print('Lattitude:' + '' + serverLat)
              serverAlt = buf[2]
              print('Altitude:' + '' + serverAlt)
              serverTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
              print('Time of Entry:' + ' ' + serverTime)
              # connection.close()    # wait for client to close
```

Comment: will this allow me to get more than one line of information from the client. I am really just trying to make a server that listens until the client closes but is able to take as many lines of information as possible

Comment: also I am trying to use the "return" message so that another file will be able to read the output of the server. So I would need to reference the serverLat serverLong variables in another file

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the socket at the end of your print logic in the ClientSocketEntry function.

```
serverTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print('Time of Entry:' + ' ' + serverTime)
connection.close()
```

Instead of closing the connection there only close it when the user sends killsrv
Because every time you close the connection on the socket it is saying that you are expecting another client to connect to the server. So maybe before going into the while statement accept the connection and then pass it into the while statement, because the way you have it structured at the moment is expecting multiple connections from different clients.